# Query string parameter name different than model property name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Have a basic search form. Is there something built into the MVC model binder that can take a different (shorter) name of the parameter and bind it with the desired model property?

For instance I want `fn` instead of `SearchFirstName` to appear in the address bar.

**Model:**

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public string SearchFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Search([FromUri] SampleModel model)
{
}
```

Sending `/search?fn=foo` makes `SearchFirstName=foo`

I know I can do something manually within the controller property by property but don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's built in already.

Using .NET framework 4.6.1

Comment: You would need to create a custom ModelBinder to read the value from the request and set the property of your model.